# Loading XML from string in javascript works fine in IE 8, fails in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have an XML file which was generated by serialising a C# object.

I want to parse this XML using javascript.

When i try to load a string as XML using javascript, it works fine in IE 8, but fails in Firefox.

This is the code i am using

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(stringValue, 'text/xml');
}
else
{
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
xmlDoc.async = 'false';
xmlDoc.loadXML(stringValue);");
}
```

Any idea why? i thought I had taken care of browser incompatiblity in the above code.
Also, here is the [XML file](http://pastie.org/1144932), if it can be of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Super wierd solution here...
Turns out the XML file had some white spaces in between, and the DOMParser.parseFromString() method was somehow loading all the blank spaces as nodes.

Tweaking my C# serialisation code like this solved the issue:

```
XmlDocument tempXml = new XmlDocument();
tempXml.PreserveWhitespace = false;
tempXml.LoadXml(serializedXML);  
hdnSiteConfig.Value = tempXml.OuterXml;
```